# Adblocker that still helps the sites I visit?

Tags: web-browser, ad-blocker

Is there any Adblock Plus like tool, that would display ads as far as the server side of things is concerned, but would hide them clientside so I don't have to look at them?

Is it possible a program like this exists that would also randomly click through some of these ads occasionally but as a background process instead of something that I have to see?

That way the sites that generate content which I like can get their payments and I wouldn't have to deal with people plastering my screen with ads.

Comment: For a specific or any browser?

Comment: 'randomly clicking through ads' may do more harm than good in some cases. What if its seen as fraud?

Comment: It would be no different than a bot, which violates the terms of service of ad revenue. So definitely doing more harm than good. If you really want to help content creators, then either turn off your adblock for their websites, or find another way like donations or buying their mechandise

Comment: @unor any browser would be great.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Ideally it would be hard to identify as a bot b/c it did not click on thousands of ads but just a few per day like a 'normal' user might. I don't think that counts as fraud for the person using the adblocker because I never entered into any contract to look at ads and it doesn't count as fraud for the website owner because they aren't faking the ad views.

Answer (score 2):

Adblock Plus already allows by default some ads that aren't obnoxious and otherwise behave. If you had something that randomly clicked on ads you'd be at great risk of getting malware. It's great to want to support sites, but it's not worth the risk. Using Adblock Plus should be sufficient. If a site wants to make money from their ads being displayed they should take care to not use misleading, obnoxious, or malicious ads. If their ad network of choice isn't allowed through ABP they should consider getting it checked out and whitelisted.
As mentioned in comments automated clicking would likely do more harm than good for the site. The best way is to whitelist the site, which makes their ads visible.